# DB multiple table update while permanent access

Tags: mysql, performance, transactions, locking

I have a set of tables in a MySql database which contain a set of related data (50 000 rows total, so low volume), which are accessed all the time (7 million/day) . Periodically (let's say once a day) I need to update ALL the data in all the tables (full refresh).

I'm considering 2 possibilities:

- use **transactions**, but I'm not sure how it will work with reads/locks
- use **versioning**: adding a version column in all tables and set all rows on the same "publication" with the same version. The next publication will have a version+1, then the lower version rows can be deleted. The current version is stored in a parameter table allowing the reading query to always pick the latest available version.

Anybody has experimented with both solutions? Or any different/better solution?

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing up locks and transactions. They are related concepts, yet different. Transactions make sure that a set of changes to the data happen completely or not at all. If you use a transaction enabled table engine, then you will use transactions when you modify the data no matter what. So, you did not outline 2 solutions,  only one.

Comment: There are 2 main types of solutions: update records in place or insert them (1 table and versioning or 2 identical tables alternating). You need to test for yourself which one works for you the best.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing an entire table

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
populate `new` with the new stuff   --  the slow part
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;  -- atomic and fast.
```

Replacing an entire database:  Do the above for each table, but hold off to do the `RENAMEs` until all the other work is done.  Then do all of them in a single `RENAME TABLE` statement.

No locking, no transactions, no nothing.

Comment: The populate bit will use transactions, unless you suggest to use myisam table engine :)

Comment: Rename table also locks the table, so no other operations can access it while it lasts. Just have 2 tables with the same structure ready and alternate between them without renaming.

Comment: If you want to change the client instead of doing the `RENAME`, go ahead.

Comment: Adding millions of rows in a single transaction may be a problem.  Please provide more details.

Comment: 1) There are 50k rows in this particular instance, not millions. What further details would you like me to add? If you use innodb or any other transaction enabled table engines, then all data modification statements will run in a transaction. 2) The client should be prepared for the alternating tables - read from a config file / table which table is the live one and proceed with that one. This is quite a common practice.